# How can you use :has() together with ::after?

Tags: css

Why are the first two examples not working?

```css
div:has(button:not([style*="display: none"]))::after {
  content: 'not working';
}


div:has(button)::after {
  content: 'this does not work either';
}

/*
div::after {
  content: 'only this works, why?';
}
*/
```

```html
<div><button></button></div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine, it's only a "browser support" issue so closing the question as "cannot reproduce"

Comment: `:has()` is an experimental feature only available in a draft of CSSWG specs that only one browser supports. You should not expect it to work yet in production code.

Comment: As well, "not working" is not a useful problem statement. How should it work?

Comment: Honestly, probably best served as a duplicate of this canonical for now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector And in the future when it is not, the question will be no-repro since once the answer is no longer "no" to the canonical, the problem of _this_ question will go away, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q:** How can you use [`:has()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#relational) together with `::after`?

**A:** By using a browser that has [support for `:has()`](https://caniuse.com/css-has).

**Safari** so far is the only browser where the current stable version supports `:has()` (since version 15.4, we're at 15.6.1 as of now).

**Chrome** [is going to support it](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5794378545102848) in the next stable version 105 which is going to be released in 5 days from now, August 30, 2022.

**Firefox** has been supporting it *behind a flag* since version 103. It can be enabled by entering `about:config` in the address bar and then enabling `layout.css.has-selector.enabled` (set it to `true`).

This is how your snippet renders in current Safari (MacOS):

[image]

which shows Safari is applying your rule

```css
div:has(button:not([style*="display: none"]))::after {
  content: 'not working';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're likely using a browser that doesn't support the `has` pseudo class. I tried running this on a beta version of Chrome (105) and it worked fine.

Here's a quick reference regarding browser compatibility:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility

### Extra info

If you are using Chrome, type in `chrome://version/` in your address bar to find the current version you have.

Answer (score 1):

You should check its support option here [css-has](https://caniuse.com/css-has) and check your browser above to know which Chromium version you're using.

This feature is not enabled by default you'll have to enable it from settings, you can get a guide here on it. https://blog.logrocket.com/how-when-use-css-has-selector/